# Cannot read property of undefined 'ngOnInit' 'getData'-Angular-Unit testing-jasmine

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm trying of write a unit test for my component file which is subscribing to a method in service layer

Homecomponent.ts

```
import { Data } from './../model/data.model';
import { DataService } from './../services/data.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  data: Data[];
  constructor(private service: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
  }
  getData() {
    this.service.getData().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.data = data;
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

HomeComponent.spec.ts

```
import { Data } from './../model/data.model';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { ComponentFixture, async, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { DataService } from '../services/data.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { results } from '../model/home';

class MockMyService {
  public data: Data[];
  public getData(): Observable<Data[]> {
    this.data = results;
    return Observable.of(this.data);
  }
}

describe('HomeComponent', () => {
  let component: HomeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HomeComponent>;
  let mockSomeService: MockMyService;
  describe('Async', () => {
    beforeEach(async(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [HomeComponent],
        providers: [
          {
            provide: DataService,
            useValue: mockSomeService,
          },
        ],
        imports: [HttpClientModule],
        schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      });
      TestBed.compileComponents();
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomeComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();
      mockSomeService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(DataService);
      spyOn(mockSomeService, 'getData').and.returnValue(Observable.of(results));
      component.ngOnInit();
      fixture.detectChanges();
    }));
  });

  // afterEach(() => {
  //   fixture = undefined;
  // });

  it('method should be called', async () => {
    component.ngOnInit();
    mockSomeService.getData();
    expect(fixture.debugElement.componentInstance.data.length).toEqual(2);
  });
});
```

if I use 
 component.ngOnInit();
it is giving error as

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngOnInit' of undefined
```

if I'm not using component.ngOnInit()
it is giving me error as

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined
```

How can I overcome this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried removing `async` from `beforeEach` and also from test ?

Comment: @Michal yeah, I tried, but still not working:(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close but not quite there!

1. Your TestBed configuration must not be nested in a describe block that other describe blocks cannot access
2. When using a mock service use the term useClass: instead of useValue:
3. There is no need to spyOn the service method when you are mocking out your service
4. Instead of testing your ngOnInit test your getData method to make sure it sets the data attribute on your component correctly. This is because you don't know when ngOnInit has finished running your asynchronous code
5. As getData is asynchronous pass the done() callback into your it block this will allow you to notify the test when asynchronous code should be completed

Also, it seems like you're possibly using an old version of angular as your RXJS version is before version 6 because your code is using Observable.of() rather than the new syntax which is just of(). Maybe consider upgrading!

Hope this explanation helped! :)

The fixed test code is below:

```
class MockMyService {
  public data: Data[];
  public getData(): Observable<Data[]> {
    this.data = results;
    return Observable.of(this.data);
  }
}

describe('HomeComponent', () => {
  let component: HomeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HomeComponent>;
  let dataService: DataService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [HomeComponent],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: DataService,
          useClass: MockMyService
        }
      ],
      imports: [HttpClientModule],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
    }).compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    dataService = TestBed.get(DataService);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  describe('Given the component is loaded', () => {
    describe('When getData returns mock data', () => {
      it('Then the data attribute has a length of 2', (done) => {
        dataService.getData().subscribe(() => {
          expect(component.data.length).toEqual(2);
          done();
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

[image]